# One to Many MongoDB lookup with project req fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, one-to-many, mongodb-lookup

I have a one to many relationship of two Collections say A to B. How can I i show the desired output in one document for each id.
For example, I have

```
/*Collection A*/
{
    "a_Id": "abc",
        "name": "xyz",
        "age": 5
}
```

...//Other docs

```
/*Collection B*/
{
    "b_id": "abc",
    "FeeAmount": 800000,
    "invoiceNumber": "A10",
    "Date": "2021-10-29T00:00:00.000+04:00",
    "PaidAmount": 200000
},
{
    "b_id": "abc",
    "FeeAmount": 90,
    "invoiceNumber": "A20",
    "Date": "2021-10-29T00:00:00.000+04:00",
    "PaidAmount": 20
}
```

//...other docs multiple for different ids eg abc1,abc2

How can I achieve the following output after lookup on base of id?
This is one document per id.

```
    /*Desired OutPut*/
//Document 1
    {
       "name": "xyz",
        "age": 5
       "availableLimitAmount": 800000,
      "FeeAmount": 800000,
        "invoiceNumber": "A10",
        "Date": "2021-10-29T00:00:00.000+04:00",
        "PaidAmount": 200000
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
         "age": 5
        "FeeAmount": 90,
        "invoiceNumber": "A20",
        "Date": "2021-10-29T00:00:00.000+04:00",
        "PaidAmount": 20
    }
//Document 2
 {
       "name": "qwe",
        "age": 50
       "availableLimitAmount": 20000,
      "FeeAmount": 40000,
        "invoiceNumber": "B10",
        "Date": "2021-1-1T00:00:00.000+04:00",
        "PaidAmount": 1000
    },
    {
        "name": "qwe",
         "age": 50
        "FeeAmount": 40,
        "invoiceNumber": "B20",
        "Date": "2021-2-2T00:00:00.000+04:00",
        "PaidAmount": 500
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jn8gb4nd6h0) for how you can achieve that.

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      localField: "a_Id",
      from: "coll2",
      foreignField: "b_id",
      as: "data",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$data"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "data": 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Updated**

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      localField: "a_Id",
      from: "coll2",
      foreignField: "b_id",
      as: "data",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$data"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "data": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$a_Id",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: It again gives result with multiple documents. i want the result in same document but different object. Means one document with multiple resulting objects for one id. A new document when the id is changed then all those id results again joined in one document with an object each.

Comment: Please update your question with the desired output like the way you tried to explain in the above comment it's difficult to understand.

Comment: @Wajih Check if the updated query works for you.

Comment: yes It worked. thanks for your time. i appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Join two collections `A` and `B` using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match) operator.
2. perform [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#field-path-operand) operation to "spread" the result.
3. `$project` it the way you want.

So try this:

```js
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "B",
            localField: "a_Id",
            foreignField: "b_id",
            as: "B"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$B" },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$name",
            "age": "$age",
            "FeeAmount": "$B.FeeAmount",
            "invoiceNumber": "$B.invoiceNumber",
            "Date": "$B.Date",
            "PaidAmount": "$B.PaidAmount",
        }
    }
]);
```